# Code iterating over the same element in Selenium when it should be over all the elements

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get the title of the elements in my for loop but the result is a list of the title of the first element so the loop is not working. How can I fix it? I'm not sure what's causing this.

This is the code:

```
titles = []
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
elem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "thumbImage.loaded")))
for e in elem:
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(e).click().perform()
    e_title = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'titleOfElement'))).
    titles.append(e_title.text)
```

This is the HTML of the title:

```
<h2 id="detailsModal" class="titleOfElement"> title </h2>
```

Comment: We need to see HTML of titles first.

Comment: @cruisepandey I added it.

Comment: what is the size of this `elem ` - do a `len(elem)` - Is it possible to share the URL ?

Comment: @cruisepandey I can't really share the url unfortunately. The size is 21 but I definitely have around 50-100 elements in the website that I need to scrape and it only seems to return 8 (all titles belong to the first element, though).

Answer (score 1):

This issue might be that `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'titleOfElement')))` is returning the first element it finds the number of times `for e in elem:` goes through the loop.

I am assuming you are instead trying to select the elements under the node `e` in the loop. For this you can use a relative path reference `./`

Without access to site you are trying to do this on I am blind here but see below may get you in the right direction.

```
titles = []
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
elem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "thumbImage.loaded")))
for e in elem:
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(e).click().perform()
    # e_title = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'titleOfElement')))
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[@class='titleOfElement']")))
    e_title = e.find_element_by_xpath(".//h2[@class='titleOfElement']")
    titles.append(e_title.text)
```